# Elegant way of duck-typing strings, symbols and arrays?

Tags: ruby

This is for an already existing public API that I cannot break, but I do wish to extend.

Currently the method takes a string or a symbol or anything else that makes sense when passed as the first parameter to `send`

I'd like to add the ability to send a list of strings, symbols, et cetera.  I could just use `is_a? Array`, but there are other ways of sending lists, and that's not very ruby-ish.

I'll be calling `map` on the list, so the first inclination is to use `respond_to? :map`.  But a string also responds to `:map`, so that won't work.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but I hope you are doing some checks before you pass user input to the send method! Yikes.

Comment: good point.  In our case, the docs clearly state that the parameter is a method name.  It's a deep enough API that this should be sufficient....

Comment: It's not a matter of documentation - it's a security hole. If they pass in a backtick, send's second parameter gets run in a shell. Is that really what you want? You're much better off examining the input in a case statement and then sending symbols of your own construction to send.

Comment: It's only a security hole if it's externally accessible.  This is the API for a library, not an application.  If they want a shell, that's their problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about treating them all as `Arrays`? The behavior you want for `String`s is the same as for an `Array` containing only that `String`:

```
def foo(obj, arg)
  [*arg].each { |method| obj.send(method) }
end
```

The `[*arg]` trick works because the splat operator (`*`) turns a single element into itself or an `Array` into an inline list of its elements.

**Later**

This is basically just a syntactically sweetened version or [Arnaud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330464/elegant-way-of-duck-typing-strings-symbols-and-arrays/1337113#1337113), though there are subtle differences if you pass an `Array` containing other `Array`s.

**Later still**

There's an additional difference having to do with `foo`'s return value. If you call `foo(bar, :baz)`, you might be surprised to get `[baz]` back. To solve this, you can add a [Kestrel](http://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2008-10-29/kestrel.markdown):

```
def foo(obj, arg)
  returning(arg) do |args|
    [*args].each { |method| obj.send(method) }
  end
end
```

which will always return `arg` as passed. Or you could do `returning(obj)` so you could chain calls to `foo`. It's up to you what sort of return-value behavior you want.

Comment: Much more beautiful than my original post.
I can never get used to the * operator.

Answer (score 3):

A critical detail that was overlooked in all of the answers: strings do *not* respond to `:map`, so the simplest answer is in the original question: just use `respond_to? :map`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Array` and `String` are both `Enumerables`, there's not an elegant way to say "a thing that's an Enumberable, but not a String," at least not in the way being discussed.

What I would do is duck-type for Enumerable (`responds_to? :[]`) and then use a `case` statement, like so:

```
def foo(obj, arg)
  if arg.respond_to?(:[])
    case arg
    when String then obj.send(arg)
    else arg.each { |method_name| obj.send(method_name) }
    end
  end
end
```

or even cleaner:

```
def foo(obj, arg)
  case arg
  when String then obj.send(arg)
  when Enumerable then arg.each { |method| obj.send(method) }
  else nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation, but in the original question I asked for something cleaner than `is_a? Array`.  Using `is_a? String` (or a variant like you've shown) breaks the original API for anybody who is using something that quacks like a String for `send`.  In fact, most users probably use `Symbol` instead.  I could use `x.is_a?(String) || x.is_a?(Symbol)`, but that's not very ruby-ish, and may break the API for some of my users.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the question wasn't clear enough, but a night's sleep showed me two clean ways to answer this question.

1:   `to_sym` is available on `String` and `Symbol` and should be available on anything that quacks like a string.

```
if arg.respond_to? :to_sym
    obj.send(arg, ...)
else
    # do array stuff
end
```

2:    send throws `TypeError` when passed an array.

```
begin
  obj.send(arg, ...)
rescue TypeError
  # do array stuff
end
```

I particularly like #2.  I severely doubt any of the users of the old API are expecting TypeError to be raised by this method...

Comment: The first solution makes sense, since send actually does expect a symbol. But I hope you're not serious about the second solution. Exceptions are not control flow.

Comment: @Sarah: random, but I think roughly 40% of all your comments and responses on SO include the sentence "Exceptions are not control flow."

Comment: @Telemachus - at least recently. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your function is named func

I would make an array from the parameters with

```
def func(param)
  a = Array.new
  a << param
  a.flatten!
  func_array(a)
end
```

You end up with implementing your function func_array for arrays only

with func("hello world") you'll get a.flatten! => [ "hello world" ]
with func(["hello", "world"] ) you'll get a.flatten! => [ "hello",  "world" ]

Answer (score 0):

Can you just switch behavior based on parameter.class.name? It's ugly, but if I understand correctly, you have a single method that you'll be passing multiple types to - you'll have to differentiate somehow.

Alternatively, just add a method that handles an array type parameter. It's slightly different behavior so an extra method might make sense.

Comment: Your second comment is a better solution, but I'm hoping for more from the stackoverflow gurus.

The first one has the same problem as `is_a? Array`: a user can send a string that's not a `String` or a list that's not an `Array`.

Comment: I'm not sure how common non-`String` strings are, though.   non-`Array` lists are quite common -- many objects are `Enumerable`.  Unfortunately, so are strings....

Answer (score 0):

Use [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html) to serialize your objects before sending these.

Comment: I'm confused.   `send` is the method that calls a function by name in Ruby.  How would Marshal help?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to monkeypatch, just massage the list to an appropriate string before the send. If you don't mind monkeypatching or inheriting, but want to keep the same method signature:

```
class ToBePatched
    alias_method :__old_takes_a_string, :takes_a_string

    #since the old method wanted only a string, check for a string and call the old method
    # otherwise do your business with the map on things that respond to a map.
    def takes_a_string( string_or_mappable )
        return __old_takes_a_string( string_or_mappable ) if String === string_or_mappable
        raise ArgumentError unless string_or_mappable.responds_to?( :map )
        # do whatever you wish to do
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Between those 3 types I'd do this

```
is_array = var.respond_to?(:to_h)
is_string = var.respond_to?(:each_char)
is_symbol = var.respond_to?(:to_proc)
```

Should give a unique answer for [], :sym, 'str'